# Does Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 support Otg?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

Does Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 support Otg?

I have read various opinions but they are all very confusing...  Please help.

Answer (score -2):

The specs say that it supports OTG 2.0, but it doesn't work.

Comment: A link to a spec sheet that indicates this would probably be useful.